# Changing Date format to en-us while culture is fr-ca

Tags: c#, internationalization

I'm working on localizing a website in French. However I am not supposed to change the date format to French. It must remain as per en-us format even if the culture is set to fr-ca i.e, when rest of the contents are in French, the date format should still be in English(en-us).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly I got a very simple answer. While setting Culture and UICulture, all I need to do is to set the Culture Property to en-us always. This will result in showing the date format in English always.

Answer (score 10):

To change how dates are formatted you could [**create a custom CultureInfo**](http://blog.mediawhole.com/2007/08/creating-custom-cultureinfo.html), based on an existing CultureInfo (in your case "fr-CA"), modifying only the date formats. I don't have any experience in this, but the linked aricle and [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx) explains how it's done. Supposedly, it's not too difficult.

I imagine that setting `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to an instance of your custom CultureInfo (e.g. in the Page.Load event) should do the job.

---

Or, use the CultureInfo class to specify culture on a per-string basis:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Whenever you write a date to the page, use the following syntax:

```
myDate.ToString("d", culture);
```

or

```
string.Format(
  culture,
  "This is a string containing a date: {0:d}",
  myDate);
```

The [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) class resides in the `System.Globalization` namespace and `d` in the above is the format in which to output the date. [See John Sheehan's ".NET Format String Quick Reference" cheat sheet](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/#DotNET) for more on format strings.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I had to set the language of the app, also determine if the language is right-to-left language, but also needed to keep the standard datetime format. So that was what I did:

```
string culture = "ar-SA";  
//Set language and culture to Arabic  
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);

//But independent of language, keep datetime format same
DateTimeFormatInfo englishDateTimeFormat = new CultureInfo("en-CA").DateTimeFormat;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat = englishDateTimeFormat;
```

Comment: thank you so much, you saved my day. Anyway, I edited your answer to reset the datetime format in the UI Culture also. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

On the string, when you display the date, do the following:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string s = dateTimeObject.ToString(ci);
```

This is a simplified example however, you just need to do the necessary work you want to do on the `DateTime` object.

Comment: If I do it this way I'll have to change the code everywhere. Can't this be done globally?

Comment: @Nadeem: It's possible to make your own CultureInfo. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Guys !!!!
Seems like your sugessions are working for me.
I tried creating a custom culture which extends the features of fr-ca and changes its date format to en-us.
Here is the code

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr-ca");
DateTimeFormatInfo dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
dateformat.FullDateTimePattern = "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt";// Date format of en-us
ci.DateTimeFormat = dateformat;
CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder obj = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("fr-ca", CultureAndRegionModifiers.Replacement);
obj.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(ci);
obj.Register();
```

Once the code registers new fr-ca, the date format of the fr-ca will be same as that of en-us.
The code can be used in Page_Load.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the above code in code snipet :

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr-ca"); 

DateTimeFormatInfo dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();



dateformat.FullDateTimePattern = "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt";// Date format of en-us



ci.DateTimeFormat = dateformat; 

CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder obj = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("fr-ca", CultureAndRegionModifiers.Replacement);


 obj.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(ci); 

obj.Register();
```