# Converting dates to internationalize format

Tags: c#, internationalization, globalization

I am reading the date from a field, and the date is already converted into the international format, thus it comes as, "مارس 12، 2012، 09:28 عصر", after reading the value i wish to extract the date out of the string. Like with English date strings we can use, new Date(dateString), is there a way to extract date in the localized format using the localized string.
Something that would work like, 
var dateObject = new Date("مارس 12، 2012، 09:28 عصر"); and give me the dateObject.

Sorry for not able to provide more information about the problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what type of field you got this localized date from? It may (should) have a property that gives you the date in a non-text format. Also, what specific culture (or locale) produced this output?

Comment: @user1045047 Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 0):

The `Date.Parse` and `Date.TryParse` methods will accept an instance of `CultureInfo` to let you parse these strings if they correspond to standard formats in a non-English culture.

Comment: I tried using "Date.parse("مارس 12، 2012، 09:28 عصر", culture)" where culture was correctly obtained. But the value returned is still NaN.

Comment: If it doesn't work that way, and you can express your exact date format in standard terms, then `Date.(Try)ParseExact` may be your friend...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `CultureInfo`? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513503/changing-date-format-to-en-us-while-culture-is-fr-ca) may provide direction.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.90).aspx) is documentation on the `CultureInfo` class.

"way to extract date in the localized format using the localized string":

```
myDate.ToString("date", new CultureInfo("ar-SA")); //arabic
```

To do this in US English:

```
myDate.ToString("date", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```