# Format dates by UI culture, but floats and numbers as InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my .NET Core web application, I have changed the UI culture to the culture that corresponds to the user. However, when I output floats etc. I want it to be as InvariantCulture, as I have a lot of problems with the parsing.

For example, in Denmark, decimal separator is a comma, and not dot.

If I have a flow of 8.5, it prints it as 8,5.
However, when I then save that (e.g. from an input to a float property in my model), I submit it as 8,5, but .NET is not able to parse it to 8.5 in the float. It just becomes 85.

Therefore I want to completely have the floats and numbers as InvariantCulture, because it's a pain to convert it all the time.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Why not format numbers by UI culture too ? Obviously this will create a problem.

Comment: This has been asked before. Basically you need to create a custom culture for dates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513503/changing-date-format-to-en-us-while-culture-is-fr-ca

Answer (score 0):

Of course, .Net can parse that correctly! That's the `IFormatProvider` argument in `float.Parse`:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("dk-DK");
float x = float.Parse("8,5", ci);
```